# Why different Asbestos types are hydrophobic and hydrophilic

Tags: physical-chemistry

I was doing research into the structure of asbestos to see that white asbestos chrysotile is hydrophilic where as both brown and blue asbestos is hydrophobic.

Could you please explain why this is?

Comment: .... homework. ;-) What have you found out? 99% of the people here likely to answer *also* have to look it up on wikipedia or someplace before ...